# Browse specific path directory in html

Tags: html, input, filepath

I have this path directory `"C:\xampp\php\images\"`, 
what i want is:

when `<input type="file">` button is click it will direct to that specific path.
Confused to do it. your help will help me a lot. Thank you

Comment: This question needs work to be answerable. [Please follow this guide to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: fisorry my bad. but example is when <input type="file"> is click it will go to that specific file path. sorry i hopes its understood already.

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want is for your PHP script to receive file uploads, and write them do that directory on disk.

Comment: you can use image tag to display images

Comment: @Brad yes. im working on my update employee with image

Answer (score 0):

@AlutiitSalsweet, from the form that you submitted.

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadImg.php" method="POST">
   <input name="userfile" type="file" placeholder="Upload This File"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

in uploadImg.php

```
<?php
...
$imageDir= '../php/images';
$uploadImg = $imageDir.basename($_FILES['imagefile']['name']);
//check file type if valid
...
//check if file name is already existed else replace the file or give other file version name
?>
```

Comment: I'm using form sir. that when input is click it will browse that specific directory

Comment: @AlutiitSalsweet, I am still kind of lost in your queries. Do you want to perform and retrieve the images and display on the current web page within the designated section?

Comment: I replace the action to that specific path but it does not go to that path. instead it browse in my recent browsing location

Comment: lets say i have this <form> inside this form i have <input type=file> what i want is when input is click it will go to this path folder "C:\xampp\php\images\". sorry

Comment: @AlutiitSalsweet, may I ask why you are not using the database to perform store and update? instead you do it locally.

Comment: yes im using database. but i think that is not the problem. people who use this system are old and hard to adapt. so im making them simple system and easy to understand. so what i need is before they create / import csv file with employee details they must first insert all in "C:\xampp\php\images\" so that they would be easy to locate the image. and easy for them to find.